# Find the first empty cell after a text in a row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project and need at the moment to find the first empty cell just after text cells in a row in Excel. To clarify, let me explain to you what I'm lookng for with this screenshot

[image]

I want to write a code to return for me for like an example in the case of the 20th row the number of column of the cell E20 even if the first empty cell is A20 but like I said, i want the first empty cell juste after the last "not empty" one. 
for the 21th row the result will be C21, the 22th row it will be F22 and there you go

Here's the code I wrote but for some reason it doesn't work, please help.

```
Function emptyCell(ws As Worksheet, ligne As Integer)
    Dim m, p, n As Integer
    Dim suite(700) As Integer

    For k = 0 To 700
        suite(k) = 0
    Next
    emptyCell = 0
    i = 1
    Do Until suite(i) = 0 And suite(i - 1) = 1
        If ws.Cells(ligne, i) <> "" Then
            suite(i) = 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
        emptyCell = emptyCell + 1
    Loop
    End Function

    Sub test()
    Dim d As Integer
    empty_cell = emptyCell(Sheets("tmp"), 2)
    MsgBox (empty_cell)

    End Sub
```

The logic of my code is to assign 0 for empty cells and 1 in the other caase, run a test to find the first 1-0 that's gonna appear in my array and get the column order from the order of this "1"

I know I'm not that clear cause I didnt want it to make it a long post and english is not my first language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will you ever get rows with an empty cell between two non-empty cells? (for example, cells `A1` and `B1` have text, cell `C1` is empty and `D1` has text)

Comment: 1) is the correct answer to the 22nd row "E22"? 2) Is there any data on the right of your search area?

Comment: Assuming that "E22"  rather than "F22" was meant, it would be as simple as `Cells(22,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1)`

Comment: Maybe practice with the special cells. Select the range, hit F5, click "Special Cells.." and you can select either text or numbers. You can also set your range using special cells, so when you loop through it you would be just looping through text or number strings.

Comment: @JohnColeman - That would only work in cases where a range of contiguously filled cells existed. If you had 001011, it would not capture the first empty cell after a non-emtpy one.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Good point, although it really isn't clear just what they want to do. I interpreted it as finding the first empty cell after the last value in the row. Unfortunately, their chosen example doesn't illustrate the full range of possibilities.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I actually think you are correct. I just re-read the question and saw this more clearly: *i want the first empty cell juste after the last "not empty" one*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All if you want to get the first empty cell after the last non empty cell, why not try it like this?

```
Function emptyCell(ws As Worksheet, Row As Long) As Range
    Set emptyCell = ws.Cells(Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
End Function

Sub Test()
Dim empty_cell As Range
Set empty_cell = emptyCell(Sheets("tmp"), 20)
MsgBox empty_cell.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: You should use `ws.Columns.Count` in case ActiveSheet and ws have different column counts (.xls vs .xlsx)

Comment: The proposed solution is for the row context .

Comment: not sure what you mean by that, but my comment was pointing out that in `ws.Cells(Row, Columns.Count)` `Columns.Count` will use the number of Columns on the Active Sheet, which may or may not be the same as the number of columns on `ws`.  Eg if the active sheet is in an `xlsx` and ws is in a `xls` this will through an error.

Comment: I meant, `ws.Cells(Row, Columns.Count)` is finding the last column in row Row (passed in the statement). That's what the OP's requirement. The last column on whole sheet is irrelevant here.

Comment: I'm not talking about `Row`, that bits fine.  Did you even read my comment about Column and how it might be problematic?

Comment: Ah. Now I see what you meant. FYI `Columns.Count` will always return the total column count and it doesn't need to be qualified with the sheer reference. e.g. `ws.Cells(20, Columns.Count)' will return the last available cell in last column and then `.End(xlToLeft)' is like pressing `Ctrl+Left Arrow Key` and it will stop to the last filled cell in row 20. I really don't see what's the benefit of using the sheet reference here as it will always return the max possible column count as per the excel version being used.

Comment: Ok, one last attempt to explain it to you: `Columns.Count` without a qualifying sheet reference will return the number of columns on the **Active Sheet**.  The Active sheet may or may not be `ws`.  Which may or may not have the same number of columns as `ws`.  It is possible that this will have no effect, or cause an error, or return incorrect results.  For the sake of three characters in your code, why just add `ws.` in front of `Columns.Count` and avoid the risk?

Comment: So all you are saying that different sheets in a workbook may have different number of columns? Right? 
BTW I have edited it as per your suggestion as this not a big deal and it won't make any difference but still not convinced. :)